# What algorithm should i use to see if i can get n from given numbers

Tags: algorithm

I'm give number `n` and x different numbers,i should find out if i can get `n` from given numbers using `+` and `-`.What algorithm should i use?
For example .

`Input          Output
   n=10 .        15+25-30=10
   15 25 30`

Comment: how big is your dataset gonna be ? If too big, you may have to use a heuristic with no guarantee to succeed, only a good probability...

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a  free coding service. How you do this manually? You may want to start with a small case, then build up with a hight number of different numbers being inputted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it dynamically. Iterate through the given numbers and store the values, that are achieveable by taking the previous result and adding/subtracting the present number. In your example it's going to be:

- { 0 }
- { -15, 15 }
- { -40, 10, -10, 40 }
- { -70, -10, -20, 40, -40, 20, 10, 70 }

Finally, just check if your value is in the final set. It looks like exponential algorithm (set size doubles with each iteration), though the numbers repeat quickly. Also, you can actually store only positive values.

Comment: Depending on the problem statement, he might not be able to drop the negative values (maybe solutions of the form 10 - 15 + 30 are accepted, there is no reason they shouldn't)

Comment: You can also speed it up a bit in some cases (not all though) by precomputing the sum S[i] from the end to any given index i. When, at iteration i of @kmichael08's algorithm, you are above S[i] or below -S[i], you know you can remove this number from your list of possibilities..

Comment: @gdelab I thought about not duplicating values, as the set is in each step symmetrical, so you can remember about it while updating it, not actually keeping these values. If you can calculate x, then also -x (negating everything).

Comment: You'll still loose possibilities: say you have [1, 3, 5, 10], if you don't keep negatives you'll get [1], [4], [9], [19] whereas with them you have many more possibilities: [-1, 1], [-4, -2, 2, 4], etc. But I agree that instead of keeping only the positives, you can keep only the absolute values of all the numbers you have.